# Are GLSL compilers well optimized

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, compiler-optimization

Are recent GLSL compilers smart/well optimized?

In other words, if I go brainless and write stuff like the following, would recent compilers save my day and optimize away the unnecessary code, or should I be always careful with what I write?

```
// All of the values are constants

if (3.7 == 3.7) // Will the condition be executed or removed at build time?
   x++;

// Will this whole block be entirely removed? (or should I use macros)
if (1 == 2)
    x++;

for (i = 0; i < 0; ++i) // Remove this
    x++;

for (i = 0; i < varA * varB; ++i) // Compute varA * varB once, outside the loop
    x++;

vec3 v = vec3(0);
if (length(v) > 0) // Remove
    x++;

float p = mix(varA, varB, 1); // p = varB

float p = 5;
p *= uniform * 0; // Just set a = 0 from the start

float p = 5;
p *= 1; // Remove that
```

There is a lot more things that I can't get out now, but you should have got the point.

Also, can recent compilers automatically detect less obvious optimizations, like the ones described there:
http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL_Optimizations

Is there a known trade off between "compilation time" versus "time spent optimizing", set up by the implementors or the specification?

Comment: you should read http://www.humus.name/index.php?page=Articles&ID=6. Short answer is "you can't be sure"

Comment: This reading was depressing. Great document through. I guess I still have to think twice about what I am writing. However GLSL seems to leave less room for some optimizations (no saturate, rcp, rsqrt, sincos...)

Comment: It depends a lot on the platform too. Mobile platforms for example don't have a lot of time to spare on optimization when compiling shaders.

Answer (score 8):

GLSL compilers are very conservative on floating point optimizations. You cannot be sure for any particular optimization. The rule of thumb is: optimize whatever you can and don't hope for any help from a GLSL compiler.

Read [Low-Level Thinking in High-Level Shading Languages](http://www.humus.name/Articles/Persson_LowLevelThinking.pdf) by Emil Persson for interesting details and case-studies.

**P.S:** This answer may sound pessimistic. However, GLSL compilers still do a lot of great job optimizing your code. Just don't count on it and do your best.

Comment: Well, nvidia's `cgc` (from cg toolkit) could be used to take a look on what assembly will be generated, but it only almost-true for nvidia drivers, and compiler version in toolkit and in driver may be different. For other implementations - "magic happens", noone appears to be willing to expose immediate assembly at least as extension (except nvidia, they have assembly extensions for all available functionality).

Comment: The linked presentation is talking about HLSL -- GLSL is quite different because the language explicitly allows the compiler to violate normal IEEE-754 precision rules unless you use specific constructs that guarantee otherwise.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: yes, but they don't have to. This is very compiler specific.

Comment: True, but GLSL compilers are written by the hardware vendors, so they have a lot of incentive to go all-out to improve driver benchmark results (often based on performance of poorly written GLSL code).  HLSL is written by Microsoft, and they lack that incentive.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Microsoft has to do it once to rule them all. Compare it to how each independent hardware vendor should do it on their own. They do the same job many times reinventing the whee... GLSL compiler.

Comment: Historically, Microsoft has had to do it because they use an intermediate byte-code that the driver translates to native instructions. D3D10 moved a little bit away from the original design by no longer allowing you to write assembly language shaders, but they still write the one and only shader compiler and use a standard byte-code. Believe it or not, there is still room for optimization by the driver after it receives the compiled byte-code in D3D, but there is not nearly as much potential as there is when the driver has the original source code (as it does with GLSL) to work with.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman in theory, yes. In practice, far less so (mostly because GLSL is too abstracted from hardware, and because different vendors have very different compilers). Anyway, with HLSL/Cg at least one could tell if compiler removes dead code by looking into assembly. In GLSL, all you could do is hope for compiler to not be dumb and blame yourself/vendor/khronos/etc. when it is. Khronos always told that GLSL may have better optimisation, but after all they finally added uniform layout binding into language - how long it took to realise that it is truly needed, 10 years?

Comment: Don't get me wrong - i use GL and, unfortunately, i have to use GLSL. Always hated its approach, tho. Stuck with assembly for as long as possible - but it is no longer.

Comment: @keltar: That is exactly my point though. There is a lot of potential for optimization in GLSL, but that responsibility lies square on the shoulders of the implementer. The amount of time and effort put into this task will vary wildly across implementations; in HLSL because Microsoft writes the bytecode generating front-end that does all of the high-level optimizations, the only thing that will vary between driver implementations is very minor. Having a standard HLSL bytecode means you can disassemble the shaders and see how well the compiler understands a particular piece of high-level code.